# Based on \$f(f) = \phi_{\beta} \; \land \; f(t) = |\beta_u| \$ determine type of oscillator

Tags: oscillator, frequency, wave, phase, sine

Imagine the below characteristics of feedback circuit in sinewave oscillator are drawn:

$$f(f) = \phi_{\beta}$$

$$f(t) = |\beta_u|$$

Based on the characteristics, how can I tell:

- Which type of an amplifier should I use: inverting or non-inverting, to fulfill the phase condition given above?
- Which frequency (exactly one) fulfills the phase condition?
- What is the value of the gain to fulfill amplitude condition?

Comment: This looks like homework. Show your attempt, and define the terms - preferably with a diagram.

Comment: I think, at first you should (a) give an interpretation of the two chracteristics with your own words (to verify your understanding) and (b) explain both mentioned conditions (phase and amplitude). Do you know Barkhausens oscillation criterion?

Comment: The meaning of the used notation is clearly based on some book or lecturer's text. We do not have them, so the interpretation of these symbols needs some deciphering work before any answer is possible. You can increase your possibilities to get an usable answer by explaining the meaning of the used symbolic formulas.